# How do i launch another program install in my pc from a button in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, cmd

i am  trying to realise this application here .
i have a separate program that holds all the détails of my Customers 
what i'm trying to do here is to create a button Inside my WPF application that will automatically launch the Customer program which is  saved in my c\progam..... so on 
can anyone help me 
thanks in advance

Comment: `Process.Start`?

Comment: @CodyGray using System.Diagnostics

Comment: thanks that works fine ..
not sure if you could help but i will be gratefull if you can or direct me to the write direction 
what im trying to do here is: create a wpf that will handle incoming call so once the Phone Rings and the user pickup , i want the other application to automatically open and display the Customer info if he exist Inside our db ,if not then add the new Customer manual

Answer (score 2):

From Visual Studio, assign an onbuttonclick event (or something like it) and use this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
Process.Start(@"c:\program.exe");
```

Comment: Yes. It is a special method in System.Diagnostics that can be used to start an instance of an application. It can be used in even more depth (see msdn for details), but for what you want, the above should do the trick

Comment: what im trying to do here is:
create a wpf that will handle incoming call 
so once the Phone Rings and the user pickup , i want the other application to automatically open and display the Customer info if he exist Inside our db  ,if not then  add the new Customer manual

Comment: What is the OS of phone are you developing on (Windows, Android,etc), and what are you using to develop? Visual Studio or something else? I need to know what phone you are targeting so I can give you some code examples

Comment: @Varscott11 WPF is a windows desktop app.

Comment: I'm using visual studio..  Working on helpdesk..  If that will help..  When the phone ring and i answer it..  I want the application to check inside my other application if that phone number exist if yes then pop the detail that is relate to that number..